# Subject-verb agreement in question

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

In the sentence " What kind of flowers is/are Molly growing? Is the subject here flowers or Molly?

Comment: *Molly is growing [what kind of] flowers* -- *Molly* is the subject.

Answer (score 1):

1-What is Molly doing? - Molly is growing flowers.

2-Who is growing flowers? - Molly is growing flowers.

3-What is Molly growing? - Molly is growing flowers.

4-What kinds of flowers **does** Molly grow? - Molly  grows (these/those) kinds of flowers.

5-What kinds of flowers **is** Molly growing? - Molly is growing (these/those) kinds of flowers.

**Molly is the subject.**